# Error al cargar proyectos ¿perdí todo? | android studio

Tags: android-studio

espero puedan ayudarme, desde el dia de ayer estoy intentando cargar algunos proyectos que tengo por terminar en android studio pero al abrir el mismo me cambia todos los codigos, dejo un ejemplo acá

ic_launcher_background

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string msgid="3698378085901466129" name="mr_button_content_description">"Igorri botoia"</string>
    <string msgid="6349900579507521956" name="mr_chooser_searching">"Gailuak bilatzen"</string>
    <string msgid="414301941546135990" name="mr_chooser_title">"Igorri hona"</string>
    <string msgid="6422801843540543585" name="mr_controller_album_art">"Albumaren azala"</string>
    <string msgid="4868457957151124867" name="mr_controller_casting_screen">"Pantaila igortzen"</string>
    <string msgid="7333862312480583260" name="mr_controller_close_description">"Itxi"</string>
    <string msgid="7924809056904240926" name="mr_controller_collapse_group">"Tolestu"</string>
    <string msgid="1227264889412989580" name="mr_controller_disconnect">"Deskonektatu"</string>
    <string msgid="8062427022744266907" name="mr_controller_expand_group">"Zabaldu"</string>
    <string msgid="5585418471741142924" name="mr_controller_no_info_available">"Ez dago informaziorik"</string>
    <string msgid="6547130360349182381" name="mr_controller_no_media_selected">"Ez da hautatu multimedia-edukirik"</string>
    <string msgid="5451884435510905406" name="mr_controller_pause">"Pausatu"</string>
    <string msgid="683634565969987458" name="mr_controller_play">"Erreproduzitu"</string>
    <string msgid="4570331844078181931" name="mr_controller_stop">"Utzi igortzeari"</string>
    <string msgid="5441529851481176817" name="mr_system_route_name">"Sistema"</string>
    <string msgid="7498112907524977311" name="mr_user_route_category_name">"Gailuak"</string>
</resources>
```

lo mismo sucede con MainActivity.java, AndroidManifest, cambian por completos con muchos simbolos "[]" que se repiten de manera incontable.

Lo extraño del caso es que, si abro el archivo en la carpeta del proyecto con Notepad++ se visualiza completamente bien, es como que cuando abro el proyecto, android studio no puede interpretar los archivos y los escribe de manera ilogica y sin sentido.

Ya desinstale el android studio y lo volvi a instalar y sucede lo mismo

Agrego:

Acabo de notar que otros archivos los cambió y aparecen en letras arabes, rusas y chinas

```html
<resources>
    <string msgid="3698378085901466129" name="mr_button_content_description">"Копчето за Cast"</string>
    <string msgid="6349900579507521956" name="mr_chooser_searching">"Наоѓање уреди"</string>
    <string msgid="414301941546135990" name="mr_chooser_title">"Емитувај на"</string>
    <string msgid="6422801843540543585" name="mr_controller_album_art">"Корица на албум"</string>
    <string msgid="4868457957151124867" name="mr_controller_casting_screen">"Екранот се емитува"</string>
    <string msgid="7333862312480583260" name="mr_controller_close_description">"Затвори"</string>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto se debe simplemente a que `Android Studio` tiene definido otro tipo de codificación diferente a `UTF-8`.

Puedes cambiar la codificación en la esquina inferior derecha de `Android Studio`, selecciona `UTF-8`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: lo tengo en UTF-8 pero el problema persiste, lo que me parece extraño es que no me deja cambiarlo, dejo una captura http://prntscr.com/n8v4kp - @Elenasys♦

Comment: Debes seleccionar "convert", asegurate de realizar esto.

Comment: pues nada, he intentado de todo y sigue igual... inicié un proyecto nuevo y sucede lo mismo @Elenasys♦

Comment: Si en un archivo que se muestra mal seleccionas la opción "File encoding" que encoding te muestra?

Comment: Ahorita solucione de una manera un poco "drastica" lo que hice fue revisar cada uno de los archivos, todos me aparecían en UTF-8, los que estaban mal o aparecían escritos de manera erronea  los acomode manualmente

Pude hacer la compilacion sin errores, ahora me queda agregar admob (otra cosa que me ha costado)

De igual manera colocare tu respuesta como la solución ya que justo un vecino me dijo que hiciera exactamente lo mismo que me indicaste @Elenasys♦